# How to get the LocalAddress in GO?

Tags: http, go, ip, webserver

I'm making a webserver in go that act like a proxy. I need to get the infos about the client to give its response.
Here is my code:

```
func main(){

    li, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8000")
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatalln(err.Error())
    }
    defer li.Close()

    for{

        conn, err := li.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err.Error())
        }
        local := conn.LocalAddr
        remote := conn.RemoteAddr
        fmt.Println(string(local.Network))
        fmt.Println(string(remote.String))

        go handleConn(conn)
    }
}
```

The problem is when i run i receive this message:

```
local.Network undefined (type func() net.Addr has no field or method Network)
```

but the documentation says the Addr type has this methods

https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn

https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Addr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling the function, in your `local` variable you are storing the function itself.

Try this:

```
local := conn.LocalAddr()
remote := conn.RemoteAddr()
```